# Do ext4 partitions contain data about their own start and end locations?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

In most circumstances, the knowledge of where partitions start and end is either stored in a partition table (i.e., MBR, GPT, etc.) or in a boot parameter (i.e., `mtdparts`). Most filesystems contain metadata. For ext4 filesystems, might one be able to find a second location for where the partition begins and ends? Maybe something like a start sector and length in sectors?

Answer (score 1):

Storing the start of the partition within the filesystem itself would be useless: if you are able to locate that value, you know where the filesystem, hence the partition begins.

Regarding the end of the filesytem: The ext4 superblock stores the total number of ext4 blocks managed by that filesystem in its `s_block_count_lo` field (c.f. https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block). Together with the size of a single ext4 block, obtainable through `s_log_block_size`, you are able to calculate the end of the *filesystem*.

Note however, that the end of the filesystem can be different from its containing partition's end. So no, ext4 by itself doesn't know anything about partititions. It only knows its own size. This is consistent with the fact that ext4 filesystems don't always live within a surrounding partition: it is perfectly valid to create it on a plain disk (i.e. /dev/sda instead of /dev/sda1) or even in a regular file of another filesystem.